# Search (row values) data from another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2 respectively.
In one dataframe I have a list of search values (Actually Col1)

```
Col1   Col2
A1      val1, val2
B2      val4, val1
C3      val2, val5
```

I have another dataframe where I have a list of items

```
value   items
val1    apples, oranges
val2    honey, mustard
val3    banana, milk
val4    biscuit
val5    chocolate
```

I want to iterate though the first DF and try to use that val as key to search for items from the second DF

Expected output:

```
A1     apples, oranges, honey, mustard
B2     biscuit, appleas, oranges
C3     honey, mustard, chocolate
```

I am able to add the values into dataframe and iterate through 1st DF

```
for index, row in DF1:
     #list to hold all the values
     finalList = []
     list = df1['col2'].split(',')
     for i in list:
          print(i)
```

I just need help to fetch values from the second dataframe. 
Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is use lambda function with `split` and lookup by dictionary:

```
d = df2.set_index('value')['items'].to_dict()

df1['Col2'] = df1['Col2'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(d[y] for y in x.split(', ') if y in d))
print (df1)
  Col1                             Col2
0   A1  apples, oranges, honey, mustard
1   B2         biscuit, apples, oranges
2   C3        honey, mustard, chocolate
```

If there are lists in `items` values solution is changed with flattening:

```
d = df2.set_index('value')['items'].to_dict()

f = lambda x: ', '.join(z for y in x.split(', ') if y in d for z in d[y])
df1['Col2'] = df1['Col2'].apply(f)
print (df1)
  Col1                       Col2
0   A1            apples, oranges
1   B2   biscuit, apples, oranges
2   C3  honey, mustard, chocolate
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Am bit confused. Actually I am getting an error as below    "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found"

Comment: @Lilly - Can you check `df1['Col2'] = df1['Col2'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(z for y in x.split(', ') if y in d for z in d[y]))` ?

Comment: Thanks and your first solution works. But my results are like  `['apples', 'oranges'], ['honey', 'mustard' ]` I tried df1['Col3'].tolist() but it didn't make it as a single list. Basically I want to apply `set` to remove duplicates on `Col2` too. Thanks.

Comment: @Lilly - What is `print (type(df1['Col2'].iat[0]))` and  `print (type(df2['items'].iat[0]))` ?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  `print (type(df1['Col2'].iat[0]))   is <class 'str'>    and  (type(df2['items'].iat[0]))  is str `

Comment: Shopuld I simply replace those `[  ] `from the string? Thanks

Comment: @Lilly - Use `df1['Col2'] = df1['Col2'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(set([z for y in x.split(', ') if y in d for z in d[y].split(', ')])))`